# Полная путаница с SQL в Builder C++

Tags: c++, sql, c++builder

Пытаюсь сделать задание и попутно разобраться с SQL в C++ Builder, но, чем дальше углубляюсь, тем больше погрязаю в путанице.

Моя задача в том, чтобы вывести список приборов заданного типа (`Tip pribora`), которые нуждаются в проверке (`Rezultaty proverki`) по каждому цеху (`Ceh`).

Использую BDE, PARADOX.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    Edit1->Text=StrToInt(0);
    int a=0;
    Query1->Active=false;
    Query1->SQL->Clear();
    Query1->SQL->Add("SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Tip pribora LIKE 'Не пройдена' ORDER BY Ceh");
    Query1->Active=true;
    for (int i=0;i<Query1->RecordCount;i++)
    {
        if (DBEdit6=="Не пройдена");
    }
    Edit1->Text=IntToStr(a);
}
```

Comment: а разве столбец может именоваться как  "Tip pribora" с пробелом ?

Comment: и скажите в чем вопрос? путаница в чем? что не работает? трейс?

Comment: @ЦовакСаакян разве не может? Программа-то запускается, но с каждой моей правкой кода становится все хуже, запутался я окончательно. В данный момент, при клике на button1 выскакивает ошибка - file or directory doesn't exist.

Comment: @ЦовакСаакян чтобы было понятней -  https://yadi.sk/d/IrClG1n-sQeTq

Comment: "Программа-то запускается" А чего же ей не запускаться. Компилятор не разбирает Ваш запрос: строка и строка. Вот, когда доходит дело до БД, тогда только...

Comment: @BuilderC понимаю это, но понимание этой вещи, к сожалению, не особо мне помогает

Comment: Все еще актуально

Answer (score 2):

```
Query1->SQL->Add("SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE \"Tip pribora\" LIKE 'Не пройдена' ORDER BY Ceh");
```

или как там в С экранируются кавычки.